# Jenkins pipeline marked as failed but all steps succeded

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I set up pipeline to build my wildfly-swarm based microservice build docker image and push it to docker repository. So I set up pipeline script and executed build and from logs (attached bellow) we see that build was successful but I get failed status in stage view with error: "Script returned exit code 1".

[image]

And the script that failed was:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t swarm-microservice .
```

It does not matter if I change script execution from:

```
sh '''docker build -f Dockerfile -t swarm-microservice .'''
```

to:

```
script {
    docker.build("swarm-microservice", '.')
}
```

I have also tried to change the output of the script result by changing script to:

```
sh '''docker build -f Dockerfile -t swarm-microservice . || true '''
```

But its not helping. What am I missing?

```
Started by user test
[Pipeline] node
Running on node-lin02 in /build/workspace/XYZ/some-docker-image
[Pipeline] copyArtifacts
Copied 2 artifacts from "XYZ » swarm-microservice" build number 49
Copied 0 artifacts from "XYZ » swarm-microservice » XYZ-swarm-microservice" build number 49
[some-docker-image] Running shell script
[some-docker-image] Running shell script
+ docker build -f Dockerfile -t swarm-microservice .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  380.9MB
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:8u151-jdk-slim
 ---> 22f79f57057d
Step 2/4 : ADD swarm-microservice-swarm.jar /opt/swarm-microservice-swarm.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 16f16f07a4da
Step 3/4 : EXPOSE 8281
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 26820815d1d1
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT java -jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:MaxRAM=512m /opt/swarm-microservice-swarm.jar -S src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41c896987ba6
Successfully built 41c896987ba6
Successfully tagged swarm-microservice:latest
[Pipeline] sh
[some-docker-image] Running shell script
+ set -e
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (tag docker image)
[Pipeline] sh
[some-docker-image] Running shell script
+ docker tag swarm-microservice my.awesome.demo.so.test.repo.com:5000/XYZ/swarm-microservice
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (push docker image to repository)
[Pipeline] sh
[some-docker-image] Running shell script
+ docker push my.awesome.demo.so.test.repo.com:5000/XYZ/swarm-microservice
The push refers to a repository [my.awesome.demo.so.test.repo.com:5000/XYZ/swarm-microservice]
2e35fec0db40: Preparing
c09cee929b6f: Preparing
5f09fc66f922: Waiting
cec7521cdf36: Waiting
2e35fec0db40: Layer already exists
063e7100cc44: Layer already exists
latest: digest: sha256:xxx size: 1788
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```